# How to package a python script for Windows OS(.exe)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, exe

I want to distribute my open source python tool.

I created an install shell script for linux systems. What is the easiest way to create a graphical easy to use installer for Windows OS?

PS: I would consider the ability to add shortcut on desktop as a plus point.

Answer (score 2):

[Py2Exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) is still the best way I'm aware of. You can do [tricky things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678180/how-does-dropbox-use-python-on-windows-and-os-x) if you're someone like Dropbox.

**EDIT** If you're looking for advice on creating an installer, start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535088/creating-a-windows-installer-for-python-a-set-of-dependencies)